# Access element of list.toArray by index

Tags: scala

I want to access via one-liner a list-to-array element by index.

This gives me an error:

```
Array(1,2,3)(2)  // 3
List(1,2,3).toArray(2) // error 
(List(1,2,3).toArray)(2) // error

// error: type mismatch;
// found   : scala.this.Int(2)
// required: reflect.this.ClassTag[?]
```

However, this works:

```
val a = Array(1,2,3)
val b = List(1,2,3).toArray


println(a(2))  // 3
println(b(2))  // 3
```

Why is that so and how to make a solution without making extra `val`'s?

[Scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/ErGtDqt/0)

Comment: Why not simply `b(2)`? If you are only going to access it one time, it would be more efficient this way. Other alternative _(if you still want to make the conversion)_ is `b.toArray.apply(2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type checker is making the wrong choice. Try giving it a hint.

```
println((List(1,2,3).toArray: Array[Int])(2))
```